# Does having a large number of event handlers degrade performace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a page with some 30+ event handlers.

Similar to this:

```
$section.on("click", "a.unselect-all", function () {
    var $s = $(this).siblings("select");
    $s.find("option").removeAttr("selected");
    $s.val("");
});
```

The page itself is not all that large.
But I feel that it's response time has become more sluggish with more event handlers.

Comment: Need more context. 30 handlers isn't a large amount. Depends more on what they do. And are you accidentally binding multiple duplicate handlers to the same elements?

Comment: If you have a lot of event handler it could degrade the performance especially if they are delegated once... because each click in the `$section` element need to be evaluated against the said dynamic selector

Comment: sluggish how? Where do you see the problem...

Comment: This is the proper way to set these up. Not going to get any better, if there is a performance hit on the page, it is more than likely coming from something else. Unless you are iteratively creating `$section`s in which case it will definitely slow performance. Event delegation should be done all at once similar to appending to the DOM.

Comment: Yes, obviously adding extra code that does something in response to events will have _some_ effect on performance - the code can't run literally instantaneously. But whether that results in behaviour that seems sluggish to the user depends on the specific case.

Comment: About 0.3 seconds delay when a link clicked and an element is shown.
Not horrible, but not "instantaneous response" either.

Comment: That's far too much of a delay. But you're still going to need to provide more context.

Comment: For 0.3 seconds, you might wish to use a profiler, or see the execution timeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, here's a similar question/answer with some pertinent info to understanding this issue: [Should all jquery events be bound to $(document)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824549/should-all-jquery-events-be-bound-to-document/12824698#12824698).

Here are some notes on large numbers of event handlers and performance:

1. 30+ is NOT a large number of event handlers.  In most cases, you shouldn't have to worry about 30+ event handlers at all (see possible exception below if you have nasty selectors).
2. If event handlers are attached directly to the intended object (the most efficient way for them to be processed at the actual event time), you will maximize your run-time performance.
3. If you are using delegated event handling, then event handlers should be placed on a parent that is as close as possible to the actual object receiving the event.  Putting all delegated event handlers on a top level object like `document` or `document.body` is generally a bad idea because that makes the code have to look at more selectors for every event than if the event handlers are closer to the actual object that triggers the event thus avoiding evaluating most of the selectors for most events.
4. If you are using delegated event handling, then the performance of the secondary selector (the 2nd argument to `.on()`) is important.  If this is a complicated selector that is not fast to evaluate and you have a lot of these all attached to the same object for the same event, you could start to see some performance degradation.  How much performance degradation will depend upon the exact circumstances.

So, the worst case is if you have a lot of delegated event handlers all attached to the same object that all have a complicated secondary selector.  This is the worst case because the event will have to bubble up to this parent object and then jQuery will have to go through every one of the delegated events for this particular event and it will have to evaluate the secondary selector argument to see if it matches the target object.  If you have a lot of these delegated event handlers on the same object and you the secondary selector is somewhat complicated, it's possible that the time to process all this could start to be noticeable.

---

As with any performance issue, if this is really important to you, then you need to do your own performance testing.  Install 30 delegated 'click' handlers with secondary selectors like you will be using to the `document` object in a sample page and try it.  See if you can see any performance degradation at all between the click and the response to the click.  Try it with 100 event handlers, 1000 event handlers, etc... until you see where it becomes noticeable.