# Can javaScript work on any newly added DOM elemets from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am not an expert in javaScrit , but i have the following concern. I have the following Script :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#DCSort").click(function () {
```

what this indicates is the following :-
1. the script will run when the document finishes loading.
2. when the DCSort DOM element is clicked .

my question is as follow:-
let say that after the document loaded , a new element with DCsort have replaced the old DCSort element , will the original javaScrip fire when the newly added DCSort element has been added using an Ajax call and i use click on it  ?
Thanks

Comment: that would be a very easy test to run and verify yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this -

```
$("#DCSort").click(function () {
```

with this -

```
$("body")on('click', '#DCSort', function () {
```

This uses event delegation to account for items added to the DOM after it is originally rendered.

Comment: what what is the difference between $("body") & $(document) ??

Comment: Document is more encompassing than body. Body here is selector for the body tag which should be all you have to use for 99.99% of event delegation. When doing delegation I usually recommend that you delegate only as high as you need to in the bubble chain.

Comment: Hi, it worked great for me, but can you please explain what is the difference?

Comment: @FarrisFahad many people use `document` as the place to catch the bubbled event, but it isn't necessary to go that high up the DOM tree. Ideally [you should delegate to the nearest parent that exists at the time of page load.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12824698/1011527)

Answer (score 1):

You need **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** in that case:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).on('click','#DCSort',function () {
```

Comment: This is sooooooo obviously a duplicate.