# jQuery: highlighting element via mouse hover very slow

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make a simple chrome extension that lets me highlight an element on mouse hover. I am trying to highlight an element (add border shadow around element) but it tends to completely slow the browser to a crawl on sites that seem to have a lot of elements, so I am looking for a more efficient solution.

css file

```
.highlight {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #FF0000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #FF0000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #FF0000;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('*').on('mouseover',function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(e.target).addClass('highlight');
}).on('mouseout', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(e.target).removeClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Comment: if it is a chrome extension you don't need to normalize your css code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding the event to the `document` instead of to all the elements separately:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseover',function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(e.target).addClass('highlight');
    }).on('mouseout', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(e.target).removeClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12824698/3558960) provides additional interesting insights about this type of event delegation. In your specific case, binding the event handler to the document object definitely makes sense.

Comment: and be aware of your transition's duration

Answer (score 1):

you can use pure CSS:

```
*:hover{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #FF0000;
    transition: box-shadow 1s;
}
```

Comment: I was about to accept your question but then I noticed that it created this weird side effect where it highlights all the parent. see the screenshot here http://imgur.com/kFfiREu

Comment: i don't think there's a way around this