# javascript math with dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with school classes on it. There could be any number of classes on this form, each with 2 fields. Cost of books and cost of tuition.

I have a 3rd field called grand total which I want to update as they are typing in the costs in the other fields.

This is how I have it set up:

```
    $(document).on( "keyup", ".cost", function(){
        theCost = parseFloat($(this).val(), 2) || 0;
        grandTotal(theCost);
    });


    // Calculate the total
    function grandTotal(theCost){
        totalCost = (totalCost + theCost);
        console.log(totalCost);
    }
```

Since this runs on every keyup, if i type in `44` it just adds `4+4`.

Is there a better way to do this in order to get the value of the field and not each number typed?

Comment: `parseFloat(string)` only takes one argument: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat I'm not sure that your `..., 2)` does? If you are thinking of `parseInt(string, radix)`, setting `radix=2` will convert from binary. `parseInt("110", 2) === 6`

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure why I have it like that.

Maybe its the reason 33.00 + 19.98 is coming back as 52.980000000000004

Comment: No thats because all numbers in JavaScript are double floats (IEEE 754) The same reason why `0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3` There is a good Youtube video that explains it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your interface and how you want it to work.

`.blur` will fire when an input loses focus. You could listen for `keyup` or `keydown` and match the [Enter] key if you want to do it like that, or you could bind it to a specific button. There isn't one catch-all answer.

One other thing worth noting - you [shouldn't bind events to the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824549/should-all-jquery-events-be-bound-to-document) in most cases. Find a sensible parent element that's not too far away from your input for it to bubble, then bind to that. A slightly better example would be `$('form').on('keyup', '.cost'...` so the event can be constrained to just `<form>`s which are relatively sparse in most pages.

Comment: I tried on blur which would work fine I suppose- just need to figure out how to tweak the code to change based on the math. Right now if I go back and edit something, it just gives me the last total

Comment: In that case, bind the event to the form then make the handler do something like `var cost = 0; $(this).find('.cost').each(function(){ cost += parseFloat( this.val ); });` - this should recalculate the entire form you've just changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest iterating through the whole document of fields and re-calculating everything every time instead of trying to add a field at a time to the total cost.   Any in-between method like this will result in an inaccurate total in many cases like you found, and additional quick-typing events, or edits.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to make `theCost` an array of costs for each class and then simply sum the array to get the `grandTotal` (a simple `grandTotal = theCost.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });` would work). That way it would still work with your `keyup` event because it would take the full numbers every time it does the calculation (so it would always take `44` instead of `4 + 4`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Many times, I see this situation handled with an Update Total button, so the action is deliberate.

```
$('#updateTotalButton').click(function(){
    $('.cost').each(function() {
        theCost = parseFloat($(this).val(), 2) || 0;
        grandTotal(theCost);
    });
});

// Calculate the total
function grandTotal(theCost){
    totalCost = (totalCost + theCost);
    console.log(totalCost);
}
```