# How to bind events to a newly created SVG element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am creating an `<svg>` using jQuery, and appending it to a `<div>`.

I can access the `<svg>` by using `each()` after `append()`, but the handler doesn't work. If I create it beforehand, it does.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testbtm').click(function() {
    var svgElement = $('<svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-content">\
               <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
               <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>');
    svgElement.children('text').text(1);
    svgElement.attr("class", "hexagon ui-widget-content");
    $("#display").append(svgElement);
  }); //end click

  $('#testbtm2').click(function() {
    $('.hexagon').each(function() {
      $(this).children('text').text('hi');
    });
  }); // end click

  $('.hexagon').click(function() {
    $(this).children('path').css('fill', 'blue');
  }); //end click
}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display">
  <svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-content">
    <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>
    <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue">
  </svg>
</div>

<button id="testbtm">test</button>
<button id="testbtm2">test2</button>
```

Comment: I would be pretty sure its because you should be using .on http://api.jquery.com/on/ to bind your click handler to something that has not yet been created.

Comment: Yep.
Try this answer >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052506/function-doesnt-work-after-appending-new-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(selector).click(f);` adds a click handler for all the elements that are **currently** in the DOM.

Because the new hexagon created by  clicking on the button is not here at the time you call jquery's `click` function, it does not get a `click` handler. You need to do this again for each new element you create (that it is an SVG or not).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function hexagonClick(){
    $(this).children('path').css('fill', 'blue');
  };
  $('#testbtm').click(function() {
    var svgElement = $('<svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-content">\
<text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
<path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>');
    svgElement.children('text').text(1);
    svgElement.attr("class", "hexagon ui-widget-content");
    $("#display").append(svgElement);
    // add the onclick handler to the new element.
    svgElement.click(hexagonClick);
  }); //end click
  $('#testbtm2').click(function() {
    $('.hexagon').each(function() {
      $(this).children('text').text('hi');
    });
  }); // end click
  $('.hexagon').click(hexagonClick); //end click
}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display">
  <svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-content">
    <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>
    <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue">
  </svg>
</div>
<button id="testbtm">test</button>
<button id="testbtm2">test2</button>
```