# Javascript code is not working on loaded PHP page using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, flot

I am trying to create a Bar Graph using jQuery flot. I have included all the required files (jQuery) in first page. Now, using AJAX, I am loading second PHP page and displaying the content in a DIV. Everything from the PHP part is working fine, but JavaScript is not working. If I include the required files and write code in same page, it is working fine. I have checked all the content of the second page is inside the body tag of the first page.

## First Page:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js" type='text/javascript'></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.symbol.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:100%;">
```

## Ajax Call on First Page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var action = document.getElementById('action').value;
    var from_date = document.form1.from_date.value;
    var to_date = document.form1.to_date.value;
    var marketname = document.form1.marketname.value;

    var url="lib/reports/SaleItemSales.php?srchtxt="+srchtxt+"&from_date="+from_date+"&to_date="+to_date+"&view="+view+"&page="+page+"&iip="+iip;

    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();     

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==0 || xmlhttp.readyState==1 || xmlhttp.readyState==2 || xmlhttp.readyState==3)
        {
            document.getElementById('load').style.display="block";
        }
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var resp=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML=resp;
            document.getElementById('load').style.display="none";
        }   
    }

</script>
```

## Second Page

```
<div style="width:80%;height:500px;text-align:center;margin:10px">        
    <div id="flot-placeholder" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>        
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var data = [[-0.2, 11],[0.8, 15],[1.8, 25],[2.8, 24],[3.8, 13],[4.8, 18]];
var data2 = [[0.2, 14],[1.2, 17],[2.2, 40],[3.2, 14],[4.2, 19],[5.2, 23]];
var data1 = [[0, 14],[1, 17],[2, 40],[3, 14],[4, 19],[5, 23],[6, 23],[7, 23],[8, 23],[9, 23],[10, 23],[11, 23],[12, 23],[13, 23],[14, 23],[15, 23],[16, 23],[17, 23],[18, 23],[19, 23],[20, 23],[21, 23],[22, 23],[23, 23],[24, 23],[25, 23]];

var dataset = [{ label: "Number of Orders", data: data, color: "#AA0000" },{ label: "Number of Items", data: data1, color: "#00AA00" },{ label: "Amount", data: data2, color: "#0000AA" }];
var ticks = [[0, "19 Jan 2015"], [1, "20 Jan 2015"], [2, "21 Jan 2015"], [3, "22 Jan 2015"],[4, "23 Jan 2015"], [5, "24 Jan 2015"], [6, "19 Jan 2015"],[7, "19 Jan 2015"],[8, "19 Jan 2015"],[9, "19 Jan 2015"],[10, "19 Jan 2015"],[11, "19 Jan 2015"],[12, "19 Jan 2015"],[13, "19 Jan 2015"],[14, "19 Jan 2015"],[15, "19 Jan 2015"],[16, "19 Jan 2015"],[17, "19 Jan 2015"],[18, "19 Jan 2015"],[19, "19 Jan 2015"],[20, "19 Jan 2015"],[21, "19 Jan 2015"],[22, "19 Jan 2015"],[23, "19 Jan 2015"],[24, "19 Jan 2015"],[25, "19 Jan 2015"]];

var options = {
series: {
    bars: {show: true},
},
bars: {
    align: "center",
    barWidth: 0.2
},
xaxis: {
    axisLabel: "Date",
    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
    axisLabelPadding: 10,
    ticks: ticks,
    tickLength:0,
},
yaxis: {
    axisLabel: "No of Orders, No of Items and Amount",
    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
    axisLabelPadding: 3,
    tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
        return v + "";
    }
},
legend: {
    noColumns: 0,
    labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
    position: "nw"
},
grid: {
    hoverable: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"] }
}
};

$(document).ready(function (){
    $.plot($("#flot-placeholder"), dataset, options);
    $("#flot-placeholder").UseTooltip();
});

function gd(year, month, day) {
    return new Date(year, month, day).getTime();
}

var previousPoint = null, previousLabel = null;

$.fn.UseTooltip = function () {
$(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        if ((previousLabel != item.series.label) || (previousPoint != item.dataIndex)) {
            previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
            previousLabel = item.series.label;
            $("#tooltip").remove();

            var x = item.datapoint[0];
            var y = item.datapoint[1];    
            var color = item.series.color;    
            //console.log(item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label);                

            showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, color,
                "<strong>" + item.series.label + "</strong><br>" + item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label + " : <strong>" + y + "</strong> °C");
        }
    } else {
        $("#tooltip").remove();
        previousPoint = null;
    }
});
};

function showTooltip(x, y, color, contents) {
$('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'none',
    top: y - 40,
    left: x - 120,
    border: '2px solid ' + color,
    padding: '3px',
    'font-size': '9px',
    'border-radius': '5px',
    'background-color': '#fff',
    'font-family': 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
    opacity: 0.9
}).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}
</script>
```

Comment: how are you fetching the 2nd page? show your ajax call

Comment: jQuery is only aware of the elements in the page at the time that it runs, so new elements added to the DOM are unrecognized by jQuery. To combat that use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), bubbling events from newly added items up to a point in the DOM that was there when jQuery ran on page load. Many people use `document` as the place to catch the bubbled event, but it isn't necessary to go that high up the DOM tree. Ideally [you should delegate to the nearest parent that exists at the time of page load.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12824698/1011527)

Comment: @monxas edited on question.  kindly have a look.

Comment: @JayBlanchard can you give me one simple example of using event delegation for executing the code automatically without doing manually?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript inserted with `innerHTML` is not automatically executed. You can check that with something like

```
document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("test"); </script>';
```

To load HTML and JavaScript with AJAX and have it executed, use the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method from jQuery. Replace everything from your AJAX call script after the `var url = ...` with

```
    $('#load').show();
    $('#placeholder').load(url, function() {
        $('#load').hide();
    });
```

Comment: is it possible to use load() without passing any url because I am using Javascript for ajax call ?

Comment: No, you need the URL in `load()`. And the `load()` function does the AJAX call. You don't need the standard JavaScript AJAX call anymore.