# Ajax call not working with other Ajax Calls

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an Index.php file that makes an ajax call and loads a php page
Within that php page that is loaded using ajax I have a html form.
I am trying to do another ajax call from Index.php that if a select box is changed a new ajax call is made.

Everything works fine but the ajax on change for the select box.

I think it has something to do with the fact that the form is loaded in with ajax and the on change is using ajax.

Is this possible to do?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#message-loading").show();

    var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "details.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html)
        {
            document.getElementById('message-box-body').innerHTML = html;   
            $("#message-loading").hide();
        }       
    });
```

This is the select change code

```
$(".selectbox").change(function()
    {
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "another-page.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $(".another-selectbox").html(html);
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

The select box is located inside the php page of the first ajax call. The ajax change should load new values for another select box within the first php page.

I have this working if I don't load the php page using ajax.

Comment: I'll add the code, sorry

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is only aware of the elements in the page at the time that it runs, so new elements added to the DOM, for example - via AJAX, are unrecognized by jQuery.

To combat that either re-bind your jQuery function or use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), bubbling events from newly added items up to a point in the DOM that was there when jQuery ran on page load. Many people use `document` as the place to catch the bubbled event, but it isn't necessary to go that high up the DOM tree. Ideally [you should delegate to the nearest parent that exists at the time of page load.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12824698/1011527)

Comment: The link you posted explained perfectly. That worked. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can access newly created element on the pages using `$(document).on`.
`$(document).ready` is only aware of elements that existed when the page was loaded.

So, for an element that existed when you you loaded the page you would use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#element").click(function() {
       alert("You clicked an element that existed when you loaded this page.");
    });
});
```

For an element that did not exist when you loaded the page, you would use the following:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function () {
       alert("You clicked an element that DID NOT exist when you loaded this page.");
    },
}, '#element');
```