# how to call a function from an external file link to the main file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i want to call a function from an external file but it shows it is undefined what i tried so far is

index.html file

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="check()" >click</button>
```

script.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    function check()
 {

alert('checked');
 }


 });//document ready function
```

I would like to call the javascript file onClick of a button in the index.html.when i clicked on click button it shows check is not defined.what is the problem

Comment: ya i included it @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: open up your dev tools and ensure the file was found where you defined it at. You don't need the check function in a ready function.

Answer (score 1):

When you linked `jQuery` in your page (I got it, because you use `$ sign`), it's not good idea using onClick on html tag.
I recommended you add `class` or `id` to the `button` and handle the `click event` with `jQuery`, like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.CLASS_NAME').on('click', function(){
        // ...
    });

    // OR
    $('#BUTTON_ID').on('click', function(){
        // ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your function was declared inside a scope which the button event can't reach. The button event can only reach at global functions or vars in the way you're using. Besides, [don't use `onclick` in the element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871640/1267304) itself, you have to bind it, like @Mehdi said:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary check">click</button>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".check").on("click", function() {
       // Perform your check here.
    });
});
```

<strike>Or even better</strike> Or you can always do this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.check', function() {
    // Perform your check here.
});
```

[But I don't think that it is your case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12824549/1267304).

Comment: Bound event on body for this solution! it's not good idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824549/should-all-jquery-events-be-bound-to-document

Comment: @MehdiDehghani sure. I updated it. In case of just one element it isn't right, actually. But in case of many elements, or even dynamically created elements, it is a good practice. I was just trying to show different scope uses.

Comment: Yes, for dynamically created elements is true way, (of course I think for dynamically created elements, if we bound on closest static parent is better that bound on body)

Answer (score 0):

Either the document hasn't finished loading yet, so this function is not declared yet by the time you click it, but I highly doubt that.

More likely you forgot to add the external script to your html. And you also have to include jQuery since you are using it ($ = jQuery). Your html should look something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of your page</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" />
    <script src="path/to/your/script.js" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="check()" >click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```