# Can I set class or Id attribute for return data in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have two php file file1.php and file2.php, file1.php send something with ajax to file2.php,

return data from file2.php, like

```
echo "<a class='test' id='test'>click me</a>";
```

In file1.php, I use innerHTML to display it

```
document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML=data;
```

I want click the a tag link and alert("something")

```
$("#test").clicl(function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```

The problem is  I cant select the a tag link with Id attribute or Class attribute, how to do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: I also cant find <a class='test' id='test'>click me</a> in page source of file1.php

Comment: Well the most obvious point is that you've written `clicl`, not `click` ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is only aware of the elements in the page at the time that it runs, so new elements added to the DOM are unrecognized by jQuery. To combat that use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), bubbling events from newly added items up to a point in the DOM that was there when jQuery ran on page load. Many people use `document` as the place to catch the bubbled event, but it isn't necessary to go that high up the DOM tree. Ideally [you should delegate to the nearest parent that exists at the time of page load.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12824698/1011527)

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function(){
    alert("hello");
});
```