# Hong browser for Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I decided to design my new job that I use Ajax and i use this cod for load page

html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="page2" id="page2">PAGE TOW</li>
    <li class="page3" id="page3">PAGE THREE</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="load"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

js

```
$(document).on('click','.menu li',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($(this).hasClass("page2")) {
      $(".load").load('page2.php');
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass("page3")) {
      $(".load").load('page3.php');
    }
});
```

This works properly ! But many times when I click on tabs Browser hangs...
My question is whether I badly written code?
Or this is normal in Ajax
If there is a way to help or not use of Ajax

Answer (score 0):

The code is not written poorly, but you have chosen an inefficient method of solving this. By attaching your click event to `$(document)` you are causing a lot of unnecessary overhead and using a lot of resources the browser could be using elsewhere.

Instead, you should try to add the event handler to the closest parent element. Like so...
`$('.menu li').on('click', function(e) {
   //Run your code in here
});`
See the accepted answer on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308940/why-it-is-bad-practice-to-register-events-to-document-in-jquery) for more information on why this is a better practice.

[This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824549/should-all-jquery-events-be-bound-to-document) has a lot of good information on the subject as well.