# Using jQuery "click" function on an element echoed by php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm making a forum and I want the user panel to change whenever a user is logged in. So by default it says "Sign in or register." But when a user is logged in it says their name and an option to log out.

The idea is that when they click sign out jQuery will ask for a confirm and if its true they will be redirected to ?logout=true where php handles the rest.

The problem is that jQuery just won't work on the element echoed by php.

Here is the PHP:

```
<div id="userbar">
    <span id="userPanel">User Panel</span>
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['signedIn'])) {
            echo '
                <a href="#" class="logout">Sign Out</a>
                <span id="welcome">
                    Hello, <b><a href="#" class="sessName">' . $_SESSION["username"] . '
                </b></a></span>
            ';
        } else {
            echo '
                <a href="signin.php" class="signIn">Sign In</a>
                <a href="signup.php" class="register">Register</a>
            ';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".logout").click(function(){
        var exit = confirm("Are you sure you would like to sing out?");

        if (exit == true) {
            window.location("header.php?logout=true");
        }

        return false;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Is your script at the top of your HTML, or is it at the bottom? Is the PHP loaded via AJAX, or is it loaded when the page is originally rendered?

Comment: I've tried both at the top and the bottom. I'm not using AJAX

Comment: First, you should update your jQuery. Version 1.3 is *very old*

Comment: Have you watched the console in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project properly? Are there any errors reported?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I updated jQuery and checked the developer tool. The issue was that it wouldn't allow me to use jQuery on https//, fixed it now

Comment: If you change the `src` to remove the protocol you'll be able to use it on HTTPS. `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/....`

Comment: Yeah, that is what I did :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to update your jquery is too old.

this the final function i create, you can try it.

```js
       function alertLogOut(){
            var exit = confirm("Are you sure you would like to sing out?");
            if (exit == true) {
                window.location.href="header.php?logout=true"; 
            }
            return false;
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="logout" onclick="alertLogOut();">Sign Out</a>
```

Comment: Maybe? Why maybe? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Many people use `document` as the place to catch the bubbled event, but it isn't necessary to go all the way up the DOM tree. Ideally [you should delegate to the nearest parent existing at the time of page load.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12824698/1011527)

Comment: my fault, Thanks for correct my answer,  i will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You may add your listener on the top of your html. Try to make it this way :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".logout").click(function(){
        var exit = confirm("Are you sure you would like to sing out?");

        if (exit == true) {
            window.location("header.php?logout=true");
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

This way, jQuery waits until your DOM is completely loaded.

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -1):

As the element is not already created in the DOM, you need to use a delegated event for it to work.

See [Understanding delegated events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

So you would do like that, but you can attach to another container if you wish :

```
$(document).on('click', '.logout',  

function() {
// Do your things
})
```

**EDIT** : I misleaded, everything is already in the DOM with PHP echo

Comment: My bad, I'm not more used to the PHP mixed with HTML syntax. Effectively everything is up in the DOM with PHP echo. Updated my answer.