# addEventListener - attaching to document versus document.body

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am writing a drag drop handler and wish to set the `eventListeners` to the highest level - which I presumed would be the `body`. However, I noticed in the [example at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop), they set the listeners to `document` versus `document.body` which leads me to ask why would this be preferable and in general, why would I choose listeners attached to one versus the other (and do they both support the same listeners)?

So when do I use `document.body.addeventListener()` versus `document.addEventListener()`?

**UPDATE** [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824549/should-all-jquery-events-be-bound-to-document) addresses WHEN to bind the events to  `document` versus at the `element` level. Very helpful.

**UPDATE2** Interestingly enough, when `document.addEventListener()` is set for all the drag drop listeners, Firefox hangs with a drag (Chrome does not). When I change it to `document.body.addEventListener()` for `dragEnter, dragOver, dragLeave, drop` it all works fine. Seems like `dragStart` wants to be on the `document` however.

Comment: Try o read this article https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-body-on-document-on/

Comment: _"I am writing a drag drop handler"_ Why do you not attach the handlers to the elements where drag and drop occur?

Comment: @guest271314 - If I have 1000 elements that can be dragged / dropped, I can either attach 6 eventListeners `(dragStart, dragEnter, dragOver, dragLeave, drop, dragStop)` to all 1000 elements, or attach these once to the `document` and process what to do with the event `target`. Since I  have to process the `target` anyway, it seems more efficient to have a global handler.

Comment: @Tareq - thanks for the link. That article linked [a SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824549/should-all-jquery-events-be-bound-to-document) which was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

`body` is but one element within a `document`. `document` is more "top-level" than `body`. But, in the HTML, there is no tag the explicitly denotes the `document` itself, thus in HTML, `body` gets used as the next best thing. Since events bubble, when the `body` reports loaded, it is generally safe to say that the `document` is loaded as well. You can see a list of events and what objects they work with/on **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)**.

That issue aside, inline event handlers should be avoided in favor of setting up event handlers in JavaScript using `addEventListener` because inline event handlers:

1. Create spaghetti-code that is harder to read, leads to duplicated code and doesn't scale well.
2. Implicitly create global wrapper functions that alter the `this` binding within the supplied event handling code. This can cause your handler to not work properly.
3. Don't follow the **[W3C DOM Event Handling standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Registration-interfaces)** and are not as robust as `addEventListener`.

Comment: Specifically, I am using addEventListener to add all my events. Just trying to figure out the best place to add them: `document.body.addeventListener()` or `document.addEventListener()`

Comment: @mseifert You use `addEventListener` on the object that you want the event registered with. `body` is rarely used in this context in favor of `document`. As I stated, the only reason you see `body` used is with older "inline" event registrations where there is no explicit way to reference `document`.