# Click on bootstrap dropdown element and change the value

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is the dropdwon

```
<div class="col-md-6">
             <div class="dropdown">
                <input  type="text" data-toggle="dropdown" id="search-input" class="form-control">
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="employee-list">
                  <!--filled by ajax -->
                </ul>
              </div>
        </div>
```

and I get the list with aand itry to get the click event but nothing its done

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#search-input').keyup(function(e){
        if($(this).val().length >= 3 /*&& e.which != 8*/ ){
            get_users($(this).val());
        }
    });

    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
        alert('aaaa');
    });
});
```

Ineed to click a list element and set the text of the input with the text of the clicked element but I can't handle the click event

```
function get_users($text){
    $.ajax({
      url: "asociate_ci.php",
      method: 'get',
      data: {
        'text': $text ,
        'option':'get_users' 
      }
    })
      .done(function( response ) {
        var employees = JSON.parse(response);
        //console.dir(employees);
        $('#employee-list').empty();
        $.each(employees, function(){
            //console.log(this.last_name);
            $('#employee-list').append("<li ><a class='employee-li'>"+this.last_name+"</a></li>");
        });
        $('#search-input').focus();
      });
}
```

Comment: use `$(document).on('click',".dropdown-menu li a",function() { ... });` as elements are getting dynamically added.

Comment: check my answer af_doubts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `on` using a single handler `a` for all elements that match your selector `.dropdown-menu`. This will be able to bind to dynamically created elements.

```
// $(".dropdown-menu") = watch for any changes to the dom inside this element
// 'click' = event type
// a = add click event to these elements
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'a', function(){
    alert('aaaa');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery handlers on present elements they work fine, 
but the new elements are not binded to those handlers so thats why we need to use the .on() method.

Change your click event like below:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'a', function(){
   alert('aaaa');
});
```

Comment: It is best practice to use a specific selector rather than the entire `document`, because of performance issues. This guy explains it well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12824698/8085668. I imagine you are aware of this, I just thought I would mention it for anyone else.