# HTML/PHP form does not work after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After ajax call, my form doesn't work.

I have a table of servers like this :

||server_name || server_port || report_date || isMonitored || Status || delete.jpg  update.jpg ||

Created by this code in : table.php

```
$edit ="<input id=\"updating\" title=\"Change Monitoring Status\" type=\"image\" name=\"action\" value=\"Update\" src=\"add/img/edit.png\" alt=\"edit\" height=\"12\" width=\"12\">";

$delete ="<input id=\"deleting\" title=\"Delete this server\" type=\"image\" name=\"action\" value=\"Delete\" src=\"add/img/delete.png\" alt=\"edit\" height=\"12\" width=\"12\">";

$table .= "
    <form id=\"serverform\" action=\"action.php\" method=\"POST\"><tr class=".$tr_class.">
    <td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"server_name\" value=\"".$row['server_name']."\"><a target=\"blank\" href=\"http://".$row['server_name'].":".$row['server_port']."\">".$row['server_name']."</a></td>
    <td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"server_port\" value=\"".$row['server_port']."\">".$row['server_port']."</td>
    <td>".$row['report_date']."</td>
    <td>".$row['monitored']."</td>
    <td>".$status."</td>
    <td>".$edit." ".$delete."</td>
    </tr></form>";      

echo $table;
```

In my index.php, I call table.php like this :

```
<tbody id="table"></tbody>

<script>
  (function worker() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'table.php', 
      success: function(data) {
        $('#table').html(data);
      },
      complete: function() {
        // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
        setTimeout(worker, 30000);
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

The table refresh every 30s. If I used the url server/table.php, the form is working, but not if i go on server/index.php, the form is only displayed.

I'm new in ajax, I did some research and it seems that's what I'm doing wrong, can you help me to fix my problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? Any errors in the console. I'd also note that your HTML is invalid; you cannot have a `form` as a child of a `table`. You should also look in to using WebSockets instead of AJAX poling.

Comment: It doesn't work when I click on a .jpg. If I go on server/table.php and click on delete.jpg, the server is deleted. But on server/index.php, nothing happen when I click on my submit button :(

Comment: Show us your click function.

Comment: I don't have a click function.. Is that what i've missed ?

Comment: I see nothing which makes your images clickable. In addition, pay attention to what @RoryMcCrossan said - you have some invalid markup.

Comment: It is in a form. Why does it not work when it's called with Ajax but work on the original page ?

Comment: If it doesn't work when you call it with AJAX then you must have a click handler somewhere. In addition, inputs with `type="image"` are not automatically clickable. jQuery is only aware of the elements in the page at the time it runs, so new elements added to the DOM are unrecognized by jQuery.

Comment: If I had to guess (which I am now doing because I cannot see the rest of your code) I think you might need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), bubbling events from newly added items up to a point in the DOM which was there when jQuery ran on page load. Many people use `document` as the place to catch the bubbled event, but it isn't necessary to go all the way up the DOM tree. Ideally [you should delegate to the nearest parent existing at the time of page load.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12824698/1011527)

Comment: Oh I see now thanks. So I just have to add a click handler ? Or the fact that I use .jpg made this impossible to work out ?

Comment: You can create a click handler for the images. And you really need to fix your markup.

Comment: You mean that is not okay to create a form for each <td> I have ?

Comment: You can put a whole form inside of a `<td>` but a form cannot be a child of `<table>`

Comment: But, isn't what I did ? Putting a whole form inside a <td> ?

Comment: No - it would appear your form is not that way. Look at the markup generated.

Comment: OH OKAY, I just got it. Sorry. I'm a bit tired..

Comment: If you're tired step back and take a break. Grab some water and relax for a few, then come back to it.

Comment: ^ that is a *novel* idea.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, That's a good advice actually :D

Comment: @JayBlanchard, +Rory McCrossan, thank you, both of you, my problem was the awful markup. I will post the answer when my work is done. Thank you.