# .on() not working on dynamically added element

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $( '.comment-form' ).submit(function(){
      // do stuff
   });
});
```

I want to target this element when it has been added dynamically. So I use:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $(document).on('submit', '.comment-form',function(){
      // do stuff
   });
});
```

But the event trigger is never added when the element is created dynamically. Is there an issue with the following:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.comment-form',function(){
```

As far as I can see, this is correct.

Comment: Binding event listeners to the `document` or `body` is bad practice.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden not really, it's the standard way to handle event binding for dynamically added elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Can you include your html?  Does the code work if it's *not* added dynamically?  Do you have any other event handlers?  `onclick=`/`onsubmit=` inline handlers?

Comment: try this $('.comment-form', body).on('submit',function(){});

Comment: @ParthShah that won't work for dynamically added elements (ie elements added after the js has been called)

Comment: @freedomn-m The code works fine when it is *not* added dynamically. And no other inline handlers.

Comment: @freedomn-m No it's not, even your reference says `Though bear in mind document may not be the most efficient option.` Binding to a parent element that is available is much better. Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824549/should-all-jquery-events-be-bound-to-document

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden agreed.  But "not the most efficient" and "bad practice" are not the same thing.  Depends on the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```html
jQuery(function($){
   $(body).on('submit', '.comment-form',function(){
      // do stuff
   });
});
```

Comment: There's no real difference between using `body` vs `document` - as long as the element in the `$()` exists when called and the new element is added within that element.

Answer (score 0):

Check this and update your code as needed

```js
$(".add_new").click(function(){
  $(".form_area").html('<form class="main_form"><input type="submit" value="submit"></form>');
});
$(document).on('submit','.main_form',function(){
  alert('Form submit');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button class="add_new"> Add New Form </button></div>
<div class="form_area">
  <!--For dynamic added content-->
</div>
```

Comment: Using `html()` will remove the previous forms. Use `append()` instead.

Comment: It's just a demo that how it need to be, and here we don't want to add multiple form :)