# Clicking a <span> tag to run JQuery javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I create a span using PHP like this.

```
if ($subnetkey  == 1 ) { echo ("<span class='subnetkey'>S/N of: $subnetnum</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;");}
```

It works, and shows the correct data on screen. Additionally if I look at it using 'Inspect Element' its properly formatted.

```
<span class="subnetkey">S/N of: 780</span>
```

I have this script at the top of the page. I've also tried it at the bottom.

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".subnetkey").click(function() {
        alert("subnet click mode");
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click the span, nothing happens. I get no errors, and of course I don't see the alert fire.

It seems like this is a timing issue between building the page dynamically and using the page. But in case thats not it, what can I do to make the function fire?

Comment: "building the page dynamically" ?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Are you making an AJAX call that pulls in the `span` element?

Comment: I'm using AJAX to pull in the data from MySQL yes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JQuery Event Methods like click(), dblclick(), mouseenter() etc. work only for elements already created when DOM is rendered. For dynamically created elements you use on() method with the below syntax (see [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)):

```
$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});
```

Since it is a dynamically created element your code won't work. Try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.subnetkey', function() {
    alert("subnet click mode");
});
```

jQuery is only aware of the elements in the page at the time it runs, so new elements added to the DOM are unrecognized by jQuery. To combat the problem use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), bubbling events from newly added items up to a point in the DOM which was there when jQuery ran on page load. Many people use `document` as the place to catch the bubbled event, but it isn't necessary to go all the way up the DOM tree. Ideally [you should delegate to the nearest parent existing at the time of page load.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12824698/1011527)

Comment: why downvote? could you explain what's wrong?

Comment: This did it, I'm not sure I completely understand the solution but I'll go look it up. In the mean time it did work.

Comment: DV is likely because this is answered in the linked duplicate.  Obvious duplicates should not be answered, but closed as duplicates.

Comment: Agreed with @PatrickQ

Comment: Firstly I updated the answer to better explain, secondly I refered to the previous answered topic. Since I cannot an answer as duplicate, I cannot see why I am responsible for that.

Comment: @iiirxs The inability to take the correct action is not a good reason to take an incorrect action.

Comment: @KeithDKaiser an explanation has been added which should help you understand.