# Read more button won't work on clicking it once but many times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is a small issue but I am stuck. I have a **read more** button for each post on a page which won't work on clicking once. It works on clicking it as many times as the number of posts on a page.

Here is my code:

```js
$(function(){
    var maxLength = 500;
    $(".content-wrapper").each(function(){
        var myStr = $(this).html();
        if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
            var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
            var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
            $(this).empty().html(newStr);
            $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">read more...</a>');
            $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
        }
    });
   
});

 $(".read-more").click(function(event){
       $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings(".more-text").show();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
            .content-wrapper .more-text{
                display: none;
            }
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
            <span style="color:green"><h4>{{TITLE}}</h4> </span>
            {{POST}}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is only aware of the elements in the page at the time it runs, so new elements added to the DOM are unrecognized by jQuery. To combat the problem use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), bubbling events from newly added items up to a point in the DOM which was there when jQuery ran on page load. Many people use `document` as the place to catch the bubbled event, but it isn't necessary to go all the way up the DOM tree. Ideally [you should delegate to the nearest parent existing at the time of page load.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12824698/1011527)

```
$(document).on('click','read-more', function(event){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings(".more-text").show();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

You may be able to delegate to `$('content-wrapper')`

EDIT: You were not properly hiding the extra content. Here is the whole code:

```
$(function() {

    var maxLength = 500;
    $(".content-wrapper").each(function() {
      var myStr = $(this).html();

      if ($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength) {
        var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);

        var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
        $(this).empty().html(newStr);
        $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">read more...</a>');
        $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
        $('.more-text').hide(); // <-- line added
      }
    });

    $('.content-wrapper').on('click', '.read-more', function(event) {
       $(this).hide();
       $(this).siblings(".more-text").show();
       event.preventDefault();
    });
})
```

**[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yeubocfs/10/)**

Comment: This code is working the same as what i have posted.

Comment: There are no errors. I don't know why this is not working.

Comment: Is this **all** of the jQuery code you have in the page? Have you included the jQuery library in the project?

Comment: yes it is all i have and jquery library is included

Comment: You have an extra `</SPAN>` in each div you need to get rid of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179759/discussion-between-wannabe-javageek-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: I have edited the answer and tested the code with your markup

Comment: Glad to help @WannabeJavaGeek

Answer (score 0):

You can do as Jay Blanchard said or you can just attach the click event listeners for `read-more` className elements after appending like so, in your original code you were attaching the click events to elements with className `read-more` immediately when the script file is loaded, they do not exist at that time, if you move the attaching of the click events to the elements with className `read-more` inside of the document.ready after appending them they will work:

```
$(function(){
    var maxLength = 500;
    $(".content-wrapper").each(function(){
        var myStr = $(this).html();
        if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
            var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
            var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
            $(this).empty().html(newStr);
            $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">read more...</a>');
            $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
        }
    });

    //Now that the read-more className elements exist in the DOM from .append
    //Attach the click event handlers
    $(".read-more").click(function(event){
       $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings(".more-text").show();
        event.preventDefault();
    });



});
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard In the OP's code they have the code running outside of the document.ready, so therefore it runs before the DOM has been modified and includes the appended elements with className `read-more', in this answer, the attaching of the click events are done after the appending is done to the DOM inside of the document.ready

Comment: You should explain that in your answer as it is not obvious.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Updated my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @WannabeJavaGeek It is not the same and I would advise you to read the comment  before the answer to understand how it is different.