# jQuery/Javascript, two solutions for click but only one works

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

I'm creating an `.item` element using Javascript, then I want to remove it by clicking. Why does `.click()` not work?

```
$('.item').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Working solution (why does it work? and why don't we always use this instead of `.click()`?):

```
$(document).on('click','.item',function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: what is the jQuery version? Any JS error?

Comment: You should add a jsfiddle with more context. `click()` has always worked for me, so you may be doing something unusual.

Comment: I'd also suggest using a closer parent than `document`, unless elements with a class of `item` will exist all the way up to `body`; you really want the closest parent element that doesn't get replaced at any point.

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions ..you never met with incident like this ? then you must havent tried anything adventurous..its events binding to dynamically created elements

Comment: I'm just working with notepad and firefox. No errors.

Comment: @musicguyguy https://getfirebug.com/ is your best friend...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.item')` returns all of the elements with a class of `item` at the time you call the jQuery constructor with that selector. You then attach an event handler to each and every one of them. It isn't designed to account for new elements.

The event delegation syntax binds the click handler to `document` and handles *all* click events. If the event's target was an element that matches your selector (`.item`), the event is accepted.

See this question as well: [Why not take Javascript event delegation to the extreme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711118/why-not-take-javascript-event-delegation-to-the-extreme)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Event delegation seems much more flexible than just `.click()`. Why do we use `.click()` at all?

Comment: @musicguyguy: Read the link at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason could be the `.item` elements are added dynamically

When you use `$('.item').click(..)` it binds the click handler only to those elements which exists in the dom at that moment of time, so if an elements is added after this statement is executed the click handler will not will attached to the new elements.

when you use `$(document).on('click','.item',function() {});` to register click event handler, it makes use event propagation to work. In the dom event structure an event from an element will get bubbled up to the document object. id if a element is clicked the click handlers attached to it and its parent elements will get triggered unless the event propagation is prevented. So in this method the click eveht handler is registered to the `document` object, so when the click event from an element is bubbled upto the document object it tests the events source element(or its parent) with the passed filter in this case `.item` and it is true then the handler is executed

Answer (score 0):

Because the elements are created dynamically after the page load...

Another solution

```
$('body').delegate('.item','click',function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the working solution already given by the OP.

Comment: *As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method.*: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: yes i know..thats why i mentioned as Another solution @Blender

Comment: @Blender ..thanks for that info i thought `live()` was depreciated..`delegate` was still there