# What is the most efficient way of registering event listeners in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, events

I'm trying to speed up my event registration. Can anyone tell me which will take up the least processing time -

```
$('#myElement').find('select.foo').on('click', 'option', handler1);
$('#myElement').find('select.bar').on('click', 'option', handler2);
```

or

```
$('#myElement').on('click', 'select.foo option', handler1);
$('#myElement').on('click', '.select.bar option', handler2);
```

Comment: The most efficient way is using [vanilla-js](http://vanilla-js.com/).

Comment: Run some jsPerf tests.

Comment: Have you considered listening for a change event on the select element instead?

Comment: *"in javascript"*?  Or in jQuery? Your second examples are more efficient (hunch).

Comment: Thanks @j08691 - think that's probably the way to go.

Comment: Do you understand the difference and what the trade-offs are? Also option elements do not have a click event in all browsers.

Comment: Is there a *reason* for you worrying about performance in this instance? You're very likely micro-optimizing your code.

Comment: I've started putting all (or close to all) handlers on `$("#body")` because it's a lot less hassle when there's lots of dynamic content.

Comment: @oriol - are we talking about a significant difference or would that be micro-optimizing?

Comment: @Matt I don't know if I'm micro-optimzing because I'm struggling to measure the effects. Our app spends about 1.5 seconds 'scripting' according to the chrome timeline (on a fast laptop), and we have over 900 events registered to html nodes. If I could make a 100-200ms gain by updating all our event registration then that would be worthwhile.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659058/is-it-crazy-to-delegate-tons-of-element-event-listeners-to-document-body#comment41920793_26659058).

Comment: You can learn about efficiency of the different types of event handlers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824549/should-all-jquery-events-be-bound-to-document/12824698#12824698 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711118/why-not-take-javascript-event-delegation-to-the-extreme/9711252#9711252.  There are different types of efficiency here: 1) Time to initially attach the event handlers and 2) the time to execute an event when it happens.  The efficiencies of those two are generally opposite.

Comment: @AidanEwen: Have you tried profiling the page load, as well as creating a timeline of it (via Chrome developer tools); that should tell you which functions are taking the longest to execute.

Comment: thanks @matt - I've spent a lot of time doing both (but haven't actually managed to isolate event registration or capture).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the commenter who said "run some jsPerf tests".  The first rule of optimizing is "don't prematurely optimize".  Why are you optimizing?  Are you having performance problems?  If you are, are you sure you've isolated it to this code?  That's what profiling will tell you.  If it *is* this code, then you can figure out what method provides more performance.

I suspect that the first version will have higher performance because it will attach the event handlers to the element(s) that are closest to the event generation.  The second version attaches the event handlers to elements higher in the DOM tree, so the events will have to propagate before they are caught, and then the event handler has to run a filter to see if the events come from matching elements.

Another way to look at this is that the first version identifies the elements that need listeners at page load time (doing the work then) and the second version identifies the elements that will respond to events as the events occur (spreading the work out and potentially creating more work -- possibly for good reason; see below).

Be very careful, though: often, the second approach is used when *elements are inserted dynamically*.  It's the easiest way to solve the problem of event handlers not being attached to dynamically-added elements.  So if you do have dynamically-added elements, then the second version might be your best option, performance considerations notwithstanding.

Comment: Thanks Ethan - that's helpful. We're optimising because we're having performance issues and speed will directly effect the profitability of our app. we've got ~1000 events registered. However profiling hasn't allowed my to identify event registration as an issue.

Comment: I see.  Well, it's easy enough to profile the actual registration; just set a timestamp before, do the registration, and then compare the timestamp, that'll tell you how many milliseconds it takes to traverse the DOM, identify the elements, and add the handlers.  With the exception of AJAX, jQuery code is synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Attaching the listeners to the same object makes actually attaching the listeners take less time, but the process of catching and handling the events will be slower.

Attaching the listeners closer to the target takes more time, but handlers will fire quicker when the event occurs.

Thanks to this question for the answer - [Should all jquery events be bound to $(document)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824549/should-all-jquery-events-be-bound-to-document)